# Condition not resolved on MSBuild OSX

Tags: msbuild

The following condition:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <FilteredReferences Include="@(SomeList)" Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(SomeList.SomeItem)').Contains('SearchTerm'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This does not work on MAC OSX. But works on WINDOWS. I just found out that it doesnt resolve the following term:

```
%(SomeList.SomeItem)
```

When I use a String instead - it works. So just for testing replace it with 'SearchTerm' - then the condition is working.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Your chance is to report it to Microsoft, https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues and then they might tell what's up.

Comment: Please be more specific about the setup: which version of msbuild are you using and which distribution (`dotnet` cli vs mono)? is this inside a target or part of the static evaluation? It would be best if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by switching from the standard used xbuild to msbuild in the build settings.